# How does Scala handle Any to AnyVal covariance in method return types?

Tags: scala, covariance

An example is worth a thousand words:

```
class A { def foo: Any = new Object }

class B extends A {
  override def foo: AnyVal = 42
}
```

In Java, the signature `@Override public int foo()` wouldn't even be allowed, and the overridden method `foo` in `B` could only return the wrapper integer type (`@Override java.lang.Integer foo()`).

Is Scala able to avoid the boxing/unboxing of `AnyVal` values in the overridden `def foo: AnyVal` method above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it does not. Scala has to adhere to emitting the correct bytecode:

```
λ scalac -Xprint:jvm Bar.scala
[[syntax trees at end of                       jvm]] // Bar.scala
package yuval.tests {
  class A extends Object {
    def foo(): Object = new Object();
    def <init>(): yuval.tests.A = {
      A.super.<init>();
      ()
    }
  };
  class B extends yuval.tests.A {
    override def foo(): Object = scala.Int.box(42);
    def <init>(): yuval.tests.B = {
      B.super.<init>();
      ()
    }
  }
}
```

You can see that although `AnyVal` was permitted in Scala, the actual method signature for the emitted `foo` is `Object` and not `AnyVal`, and `Int` is boxed.

Answer (score 0):

Yuval's answer can be generalized: erasure of `AnyVal` is `Object` (you can see this e.g. by entering `classOf[AnyVal]` in the REPL), so whenever you have `AnyVal` in Scala, you can expect `Object` in bytecode.

E.g. if you change `A` to

```
class A { def foo: AnyVal = 0 }
```

it's still `Object`.

Maybe there is *some* situation in which using `AnyVal` itself will avoid boxing, but I would be surprised. It was created pretty much for compiler's convenience, and picked up another use ([value classes](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/value-classes.html)) later, but it's rarely useful in user code (except for defining value classes).